# Running parallel tasks in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I am using `NSOperationQueue` to run the task. I am using background processing in my application. But while adding tasks in `NSOperationQueue`, I found that tasks will be added in a queue format.

1. Does `NSOperationQueue` performs parallel task or sequential task processing?
2. If not parallel, then how can I achieve parallel task operations in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you read [this document about concurrency programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091). The relevant information for you is:

> Operation queues work with the system to restrict the number of concurrent operations to a value that is appropriate for the available cores and system load.
>
> Although the NSOperationQueue class is designed for the concurrent execution of operations, it is possible to force a single queue to run only one operation at a time. The setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: method lets you configure the maximum number of concurrent operations for an operation queue object. Passing a value of 1 to this method causes the queue to execute only one operation at a time. Although only one operation at a time may execute, the order of execution is still based on other factors, such as the readiness of each operation and its assigned priority.

Comment: Thanks Sascha this gives me a little understanding of concurrency operations. I am using multithreading first time. i'll surly look into the documents. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can perform parallel tasks by using "`performSelectorInBackground`" method. In this you are just showing the foreground tasks, meanwhile background tasks is being in progress. I have already answered on the following link, please follow the link given below with accepted answer. Perhaps it will help you.

```
http://[stackoverflow.com/questions/8725636/cant-get-the-activity-indicator-to-show-on-iphone-app/8725875#8725875][1]
```

Thanks!

Regards!
Khalid Usman

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` to set the number of concurrent operations.